# Error while installing kernel from source

Tags: kernel, compiling

I get the following error when I try to compile kernel version 3.17.0-rc5:

`Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.17.0-rc5+ (x86_64)`

Why do I get this error and what does it mean?

Full output:

```
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.17.0-rc5+ arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
        System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.17.0-rc5+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc5+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.17.0-rc5+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc5+
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.17.0-rc5+ (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.17.0-rc5+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc5+
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.17.0-rc5+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.17.0-rc5+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc5+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.17.0-rc5+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc5+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.17.0-rc5+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc5+
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc5+
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.17.0-rc5+
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-rc5+.old
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.17.0-rc5+
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found Mac OS X on /dev/sda2
done
```

I am following the instructions on [kernelnewbies.org](http://kernelnewbies.org/OPWfirstpatchSetup).

```
make
make -j16
sudo make modules_install 
sudo make install
```

Comment: Is that the entire error message? If the whole log is too long, post to http://paste.ubuntu.com and add a link in the question.

Comment: See, it says "Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information." So you could look at that log, or post it here if you can't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually ask a question, I assume your question is "Why do I get this error and what does it mean?".

The problem is not with the kernel compilation process, which seems to have gone fine. Rather, the error occurs when dkms (the third-party driver manager) tries to compile your wifi driver for the new kernel. The compilation fails, most probably because the driver is not compatible with the kernel version you are compiling.

Comment: Thanks. Can I disable dkms? I just want to experiment so i could live without wifi.

Comment: The wifi driver has not been installed, but everything else seems to be fine. Have you tried booting into the new kernel?